# How to force clean local storage for Photos.app?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I recently noticed that my photos Library is using over 50GB of storage space on my local storage on my MacBook Pro even though I have setup "iCloud Photos" with "Optimise Mac Storage" option selected on the device.

Is there any way to force clean the cached images on my local storage?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It will “optimise” when there’s a space crunch.

Comment: @anki I am having a space crunch. I have less than 2GB space available on my disk.

Comment: See About this Mac -> storage -> manage -> space used by photos. Finder is incorrect sometimes.